# How to implement "open app" admob ad in flutter?

Tags: flutter, admob

We are trying to implement "Open App" ad by google admob on a flutter app. However, I cannot find any guide. does anybody know how to implement it?
reference: https://flutter.dev/ads

Answer (score 3):

Add the google mobile ads flutter package.
Then add the following into your main class.

```
import 'package:google_mobile_ads/google_mobile_ads.dart';

AppOpenAd? myAppOpenAd;


loadAppOpenAd() {
  AppOpenAd.load(
      adUnitId: AdIds.appOpenAdUnitId, //Your ad Id from admob
      request: const AdRequest(),
      adLoadCallback: AppOpenAdLoadCallback(
          onAdLoaded: (ad) {
            myAppOpenAd = ad;
            myAppOpenAd!.show();
          },
          onAdFailedToLoad: (error) {}),
      orientation: AppOpenAd.orientationPortrait);
}

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  //________________________________Mobile Ads initialize
  await MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  loadAppOpenAd();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

 
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

....
```

Answer (score 1):

Follow the below link and make sure to call show() on **_appOpenAd** inside **onAdLoaded** of AppOpenAdLoadCallback

https://developers.google.com/admob/flutter/app-open

Answer (score 0):

This is not part of google's official AdMob package for flutter, but I found this package that should work for App Open ads.

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_admob_app_open